# why my function doesn't convert json file to array json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

showArray is a function witch show the content of json file, what's wrong in my function? why it doesn't work

```
function getArray() {
    var quest = [];
    $.getJSON('data.json', function (json) {
        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var item = json[key];
                quest.push({
                    Name:item.Name
                });
            }
        }
        callback(quest);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    getArray();
});
function showArray() {
    var callback = function (quest) {
        console.log(quest)
    }
}
```

Comment: that's should to works..

Comment: Are you expecting the `callback` inside showArray to be called? It is scoped inside `showArray` so `getJSON` cannot access it.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`.

Answer (score 1):

`callback` is a **local** variable.  You need to get it to the `getArray()` function, probably by passing it as a parameter.